# Checking if a string has all unique characters

Tags: c++, strings

I'm wondering if this code can be optimized in terms of time complexity. The problem is checking to see if a string has all unique characters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Assuming ASCII 

bool checkString (string user) {
    if (user.length() > 256) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    //creating a boolean array of size 256
    //setting all values to false (0)
    bool check[256] = {false};   

    for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++)
        {
        int value = user.at(i); 
            if (check[value] == true)
            {
                return false; 
            }

            else 
            {
                check[value] = true;
            }
        }
    return true;
}


int main() {

    string user;
    cout << "Please enter in a string: ";
    cin  >> user;

    cout << checkString(user) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not very good with determining the time complexity. Right now, would it be \$O(n^2)\$ (because of the `for` loop)?

Comment: I think this is just **O(n)** because it only has one for loop.

Comment: @Sometowngeek thank you! The for loop = n, and then the if statement = n, so 2n = O(n)?

Comment: With the Big-O notation, the coefficients are ignored. So if it has three separate for loops, and an if statement, it's still **O(n)**, not *O(4n)*.

Comment: [Interview Cake](https://www.interviewcake.com/article/java/big-o-notation-time-and-space-complexity) has a good explanation of Big-O Notation.

Comment: @Sometowngeek great, thanks very much for responding. Will check Interview Cake out!

Comment: [John Feminella's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2307314/3993154) also has examples for Big-O notation.

Comment: the 256 length check on user is confusing . At first glance it looks like it is associated with the `check[256]`

Comment: @pm100 I should probably comment my code out more for better understanding; but what I meant was a check that if a string contains more than 256 characters, it would have to have repeats (if the string is ASCII not unicode), therefore return false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks good to me from a big-O point of view.

C++wise, you have some misconceptions:

```
//setting all values to false (0)
bool check[256] = {false};
```

This explicitly initializes only the *first* element to `false`; the remaining 255 elements are value-initialized, which in layman's terms means zero-initialized, which means yes they're initialized to `false` as well in this case; but your comment is misleading, in that

```
bool uncheck[256] = {true};
```

would **not** initialize all 256 elements to `true` — it would explicitly initialize the *first* element to `true` and then value-initialize the other 255 elements (to `false`).

---

```
for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++)
    {
    int value = user.at(i); 
        if (check[value] == true)
        {
            return false;
```

This indentation is all screwed up. You should indent whenever you enter a new scope, and dedent when leaving a scope. So for example it would be sensible to write

```
for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++)
{
    int value = user.at(i); 
    if (check[value] == true)
    {
        return false;
```

but actually most programmers would just write

```
for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); ++i) {
    int value = user[i]; 
    if (check[value]) {
        return false;
```

(notice the cuddled braces, the removal of the explicit test-for-equality with `true`, the default preference for `++i` over `i++`, and the preference for fast `operator[]` over slow `.at()` when the index is statically known to be in-bounds).

---

```
bool checkString (string user)
```

This function signature tells the function to take the parameter `user` by value, which means "make a copy." Since you don't *need* a copy for any reason, you should by default prefer to take a reference:

```
bool checkString(const string& user)
```

(and notice the removal of the extra space in between the function name and its parameter list; we don't write `f (x)` in C++ for the same reason you don't write “*f*  (*x*)” in math class).

---

It might be an interesting research project for you to figure out what you'd have to change to make `// Assuming ASCII` no longer required.

Comment: Expressing your system as `Most programmers` is wrong. Yes that style is popular but "most" is a stretch (especially in C++). Express the different styles available and name them.

Answer (score 1):

This extract:

```
    int value = user.at(i); 
    if (check[value] == true)
```

has a serious problem - if the character at `i` is negative, you'll index off the beginning of the array.  (Remember, it's implementation-defined whether plain `char` is a signed or unsigned type).

It's more idiomatic (and slightly safer) to use a range-based `for` loop:

```
for (auto c: user) {
     auto& f = check[reinterpret_cast<unsigned_char>(c)];
     if (f) return false;
     f = true;
}
```

(The extra safety is because you no longer need to ensure that you're counting the same container as you're indexing - which can be an issue in bigger functions).

Also, prefer to avoid `using namespace`, particularly at global scope.  You might choose to have it inside your throwaway `main`, but is it really that hard to write `std::` once in your function signature?  It can save you from unpleasant surprises.

Other issues already addressed in existing answers, so I won't mention them here.

Comment: Nice spot. Most people forget that char could be either signed or unsigned.

Comment: as an aside, note he says 'assuming ASCII' . That doesnt have chars >127. He should still verify tho.